# Flutter IOS build app for testing on a certain device XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ipa, codemagic

I am trying to test my app on an IOS device, but I am facing some problems.I do not have an apple developer accout. I have tried these:

1. Using Codemagic to get adhoc file. But the problem is that I need a certification, which I don't have. I want to try the app before buying a developer account.
2. I was able to find a mac with OS version 10:13. The XCode version is 9.2 which the Flutter does NOT support! So I can't even build directly to my device.
3. The cydia impactor: Looke like this is not working anymore.

Please help me run my app on IOS device. My app works fine on multiple Android devices.

**UPDATE**

The Codemagic has latest XCode for building IOS. But I can not find any way to get an app file for IOS (like apk for android).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an Apple Developer Account to test on a Device. A normal AppleID will be enough. Publishing to the Apple Appstore will required one though.

All you need is XCode at the required version for your Flutter version. The only way you could test on XCode 9.2 is to downgrade Flutter to an earlier version that supports a lower XCode version (I have not tried this).

Sadly I don't think there are any other ways around these restrictions.